# Full Text search with scandic letters crashes MySQL

Tags: mysql, crash, full-text-search, character

MySQL has lately been crashing often and I've tried to crack down what might cause it.

SHOW PROCESSLIST and mtop show that FULL TEXT queries with scandinavian letters (ÄÖ) are hanging and locking the table.

In the processlist the scandic letters are shown as "?FFFFFFFFFFC3?FFFFFFFFFFA4", so I'm not sure if this is some sort of character encoding problem.

Some example queries that are stuck in the processlist:

SELECT ... FROM `comments` WHERE (MATCH(word) AGAINST('%l?FFFFFFFFFFC3?FFFFFFFFFFA4pitunkeva*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

> should read 'läpitunkeva'

SELECT idiom FROM idioms WHERE MATCH (idiom) AGAINST ('hymi?ffffffffffc3?ffffffffffb6')

> should read 'hymiö'

MySQL - 5.0.51a MyISAM UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a MySQL 5.0 bug found here http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=37067

Seems that MySQL upgrade to 5.1 is the only option.

I haven't found a solution to fix this without upgrading MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Check the character set of your MySQL DB/schema. If it's not set, the default is latin1.

You can check the appropriate charsets in the MySQL docs. But I usually use 'utf8' in general.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-charsets.html

Comment: I checked the character set and it's UTF8 like it should be.
character_set_database: utf8 -  collation_database: utf8_swedish_ci

Comment: Ah, how is the string passed to the mysql statement? This could be where the problem is happening.

Comment: You are right I think it's PHP passing that string in wrong encoding, since I found out that one PHP script was mistakenly saved in Western (Windows Latin 1) encoding.

After changing the file encoding to UTF8 this problem does not happen so often anymore, but still sometimes.

How to check encoding/encode strings in PHP before sending them to MySQL query?

Comment: mb-detect-encoding should detect the string. Posted the link,
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php

Then I guess utf8-encode should do the trick, http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php